# Replicate Top Conversion Path by Bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Based on [Google Analytics sample dataset](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7586738?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) I want to replicate the Top Conversion Path in Google Analytics by Bigquery. Anyone has any idea?
[image]

The expected Output, the columns from left to right be like:
[image]

[image]
I want to find out the timestamp for each source/medium path also. For example, the source/medium path is `A` > `B` > `C` > `Purchase`, at which timestamp did `A`, `B`, `C` etc happen?

Thanks in advance. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: can you add the expected output as table

Comment: Hi Batra, updated, can you help?

Answer (score 2):

it's hard to get an table grouped by the path because the paths can vary a lot based on the clicks the client did during the session.

The key here for you is use an aggregation function to convert the paths (that are mostly stored in `RECORDS`) to an string. To do this, I'm using this nice aggregation function `STRING_AGG(hits.page.pagepath," > ")` with the separator `>`, as you did in your example.

Here is an *croqui* with almost you need, please check the schema of the public dataset and personalize the fields you need.

```
WITH
  pathTable AS (
  SELECT
    visitId,
    AVG(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)/10000 AS revenue,
    STRING_AGG(hits.page.pagepath," > ") AS Fullpath
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    totals.totalTransactionRevenue IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
    visitId)
SELECT
  date,
  a.visitId,
  a.clientid,
  a.device.devicecategory,
  p.revenue,
  p.Fullpath
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` AS a
JOIN
  pathTable AS p
ON
  p.visitId = a.visitId
LIMIT
  10;
```

And that is the example output for it:
[image]

- This [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en#query5_AvgAmountOfMoneySpentPerVisit&zippy=%2Cin-this-article) contains some examples of how to query there public datasets.
- Another interesting [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions) for you to undesrtand better about aggregation functions.

Comment: Thanks ewertonvsilva for your kind help. I think it's not what Google Analytics appears (picture 1). I need source/ medium path. Page path is different. #Conversions means, everytime you make a purchase, it is 1 conversion and calculate the revenue. Let me think for a while, if I am able to apply your logic in my task. Thanks anyway!